# onItemClick and onItemLongClick not firing in ListView until an item has been pressed once

Tags: android, listactivity

In my ListView I have these two methods, and they DO work, but not until one of the list items have been pressed once. So, nothing happens the first time I press/hold an item, but the next time I press/hold an item it works perfectly.

Here's my onListItemClick method

```
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            File file = new File(path.get(position));
            longClick(file);
            Log.d(TAG, "onItemLongClick");
            return true;
        }
    });

    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position ,long id) {
            File file = new File(path.get(position));
            player(file);
            Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick");
        };
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `setOnItemLongClickListener` and `setOnItemClickListener` inside of `onListItemClick`, so They won't fire until you press the ListItem for the first time.

What you need to do is to this code outside of `onListItemClick`.

```
getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            File file = new File(path.get(position));
            longClick(file);
            Log.d(TAG, "onItemLongClick");
            return true;
        }
    });

    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position ,long id) {
            File file = new File(path.get(position));
            player(file);
            Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick");
        };
    });
```

Comment: I'm getting a few errors when I copy this directly into my ListActivity. Sorry, I'm pretty new to java/android. Does this code need to be inside a method? Or will I need to change it slightly because I'm using a ListActivity?

Comment: The code needs to be inside `onCreate()` after `setContentView(...);`